# Conditional mutation in base R

Tags: r

I have this dataframe:

```
gender <- c("m", "m", "f", "f")
value <- c(75, 50, 20, 80)
df <- data.frame(gender, value)
df
```

I want to change the values in the column "value", conditional uppon the value on column "gender".

If the target change is a fixed number or character, the mutation is straightforward:

```
df$value[df$gender == "m"] <- 1
```

However, if the target value is a mutation of the original value, like this

```
df$value[df$gender == "m"] <- df$value * -1
```

I get the following error:

```
> Warning message:
> In df$value[df$gender == "m"] <- df$value * -1 :
> number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Is the conditional mutation with a variable target value possible in base R?

Comment: A mathematical way of doing this: `df$value <- df$value * (2 * (df$gender != 'm') - 1)`

Answer (score 1):

You have different length in your code, as said in the error message. You can try this: `df$value[df$gender == "m"] <- df$value[df$gender == "m"] * -1`

Answer (score 1):

consider `ifelse()`, like so:

```
df$value <- ifelse(df$gender == 'm', df$value * -1, df$value)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, you just have to make sure they are the same length as the error says. What you probably want to do is this:

```
> length(df$value[df$gender == 'm'])
[1] 2
> length(df$value)
[1] 4

df$value[df$gender == "m"] <- df$value[df$gender == "m"] * -1
```

Comment: same as Zhiya but tiny bit later :)

Answer (score 0):

Or use `with()`.

```
df$value <- with(df, ifelse(gender == "m", value - 1, value))
```